# In SSAS, can you ignore table relationships at the cube level?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

We have a situation where, because OLAP is using a single DataSource view for all cubes, some of our aggregations are getting confused.

The problem is the following:
  - Multiple fact tables join to another table to make a dimension
  - Another fact table joins to those fact tables to make dimensions
  - OLAP doesn't know which join to follow and picks the wrong one

Here is how our cubes are defined

```
Cube A:
[FactTable A]->[Dim A]

Cube B:
[FactTable B]->[Dim A]

Cube C:
[FactTable C]
    |--------->[FactTable A]->[Dim A]
    |--------->[FactTable B]
```

Because of this the datasource view looks like this:

```
[FactTable C]
    |--------->[FactTable A]->[Dim A]
    |--------->[FactTable B]->[Dim A]
```

OLAP doesn't know how to aggregate Dim A. Is there a way to ignore that join for Cube C? Can you define the relations at the cube level alone?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was doing things wrong. You should, in fact, create one datasource view per cube and define the relationships there.